# Telerik after filtering radgrid export buttons not working

Tags: vb.net, telerik, export, radgrid

I am working with telerik, and want to export data from radgrid in my vb.net web application. After filter grid, when click on export button, nothing works and itemCommand header(refresh button, export buttons) hide automatically.
But export grid without filter , working perfectly.

```
<telerik:RadGrid ID="RadGrid1" runat="server" OnNeedDataSource="radgrid1_NeedDataSource" ShowStatusBar="true" AllowPaging="True" Skin="Windows7" AllowCustomPaging="false" PageSize="25" GridLines="None" AutoGenerateColumns="false" AllowSorting="true" AllowColumnResize="true">
    <PagerStyle Mode="NextPrevNumericAndAdvanced"></PagerStyle>
    <MasterTableView Width="100%" CommandItemDisplay="Top" ShowHeader="true">
        <Columns>
            <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="assettagnumber" HeaderText="Tag Number" SortExpression="assettagnumber" UniqueName="assettagnumber">
                <HeaderStyle Width="80px" />
            </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
        </Columns>
        <CommandItemSettings ShowExportToWordButton="true" ShowAddNewRecordButton="false" ShowExportToExcelButton="true" ShowExportToPdfButton="false" ShowExportToCsvButton="true" />
    </MasterTableView>
    <ExportSettings IgnorePaging="true" OpenInNewWindow="true" ExportOnlyData="true">
    </ExportSettings>
    <ClientSettings>
        <Scrolling AllowScroll="True" EnableVirtualScrollPaging="false" SaveScrollPosition="True" UseStaticHeaders="True" />
    </ClientSettings>
</telerik:RadGrid>
```

I want to export filtered grid data.
Please tell me the possible solution.
Thanks..

Comment: One more things I have seen, by default when click on export button, working, but when click on refresh button then export button, export not working.